# Is it possible to determine the approximate age of these bricks only by seeing their injection points?

Tags: piece-information, vintage

Is it possible to determine the approximate age of these bricks only by seeing their injection points?
[image]

Comment: Maybe it is easier to determine the age if we could see the other sides, too.

Comment: Are you asking the question to see if it's possible to know the age only from the injection points, or do you just want to know the age of the bricks? Your question is clear, but it's just a kinda strange thing to ask..

Comment: Yes, they are from the 1960's from what i can remember

Comment: @Slickster. I found a pile of those in an ebay buy of used bricks and was interested in the age.

Comment: @Aziraphale. yep, will see if i can post more pictures the next days.

Comment: @Slickster. I changed the question based on your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot tell by the injection markings but having been a lego collector since 1967 I can tell that they are around that era. They look like some of the original ABS plastic. I also have some even older lego bricks in my collection (circa 1960) and they are of a different plastic but you cannot see the molding points on those.